# Pythonic way to reshape dataframe for LSTM input in Keras

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keras, lstm

I want to build a simple LSTM that takes as input the last 4 observations to make a prediction for the next time point. Each observation is a 5-tuple.

I realize LSTM wants something in the format `[num_samples, time_steps, features]`. For example if I had 100 people, I would want something in the shape of [100, 4, 5].

However, my dataset is in this format (currently loaded as a pandas dataframe -- also anonymized):

```
            col1  col2 col3 col4 col5
id date
x1 01-01-22  43   304  340  340  394
x1 01-02-22  65  595  304  204  124
...
x1 09-10-22  54 340  283. 194  304
x2 02-01-22 ...
...
```

Note, the id and date are index values. Each id has multiple observations, sometimes 100's. I want to take every group of 5 sequential dates per id to make a dataset that I can then pass into something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, activation='relu', input_shape=[None, 4,5]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

I believe putting in the None in the beginning parameter will make it infer the correct shape  but how do I rearrange my data int he correct format. I can do some ugly for loop where I keep track of the indices and the dates and append to a dataframe but I'm hoping there's a cleaner way?

Comment: Could you provide a [example]? For example, what is the type of `model`? What module did you import to have `LTSM` amd `Dense` defined?

Comment: @EvensF Thanks for the suggestion. I've added the import of tensorflow and where it would read from.